# How to multi-trigger on property and binding in wpf style

Tags: wpf, datagrid, triggers

I have datagrid in my view and I am trying to trigger a style for the DataGridRowHeader so that it has a particular background when both of the following are true:

1. IsDirty=True                      (Property on the DataContext of the row)
2. IsRowSelected=True   (Property on the DataGridRowHeader)

How do I write a multi-trigger that triggers for the above paired conditions as my following style code throws InvalidOperationException/{"Must have non-null value for 'Property'."}:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridStandardRowHeaderStyle" TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsDirty}" Value="True" />
                <Condition Property="IsRowSelected" Value="True" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightYellow" />
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 4):

The mistake in my style code finally got across to me and the correct one that now works for me is given below:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridStandardRowHeaderStyle" TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsDirty}" Value="True" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsRowSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightYellow" />
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```